Navigation Drawer opens unwanted
I am new to Vue 2 and trying to figure out why the navigation-drawer acting like it does. The following codepen contains a small nav. Which can be open and closed with the chevron icons. Which is workine fine.
Unfortunately the drawer also opens if the user clicks on a item, which I definitively do not want. The user should decide if extended navbar or minimized navbar only.
How can I prevent that behavior?
https://codepen.io/icoded/pen/qBwLqxp?editors=1010


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      drawer: true,
      items: [
        { title: 'Home', icon: 'mdi-home-city' },
        { title: 'My Account', icon: 'mdi-account' },
        { title: 'Users', icon: 'mdi-account-group-outline' },
      ],
      mini: true,
    }
  },
})
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        :mini-variant.sync="mini"
        permanent
      >
        <v-list-item class="px-2">
          <v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/85.jpg"></v-img>
          </v-list-item-avatar>
  
          <v-list-item-title>John Leider</v-list-item-title>
  
          <v-btn
            icon
            @click.stop="mini = !mini"
          >
            <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-list-item>
        
         <div
        :style="{ display: mini ? 'block' : 'none' ,paddingLeft: '20px', paddingTop: '5px', paddingBottom: '5px' }"
      >
        <v-icon
          @click="mini = !mini"
        > mdi-chevron-right </v-icon>
      </div>
  
        <v-divider></v-divider>
  
        <v-list dense>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.title"
            link
          >
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
  
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>



VG

Change v-navigation-drawer to keep mini as true when list items attempt to update it.
<v-navigation-drawer
  v-model="drawer"
  :mini-variant.sync="mini"
  permanent
  @update:mini-variant="mini = true"
>

Chevron to open/close will still work fine.
